# Change first responder in uitableview custom cell?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uitextfield, custom-cell, first-responder

I'm having a tableview which uses custom cell for the cells. Each cell has four text fields. When I work in first text field and click next in keyboard I want to make the next text field in the same cell to become the first responder. Can anyone help please?